# how to convert a string to an int in java and and separate the values of the string?

Tags: java

I am working on a board style game in java. currently the board is initialized in a 2d array. A player can make a move by enter the color of his chip plus his move so for example by entering: "W c 3" W = the color of the chip/player c is the letter corresponding to the column and 6 is the row. I need to be able to get the values from the string and update the board's row and column. So " a 1" should be row =1 col = 1. "b 1" should be row = 1 col = 2 "e 5" would be row = 5 col = 5 as an example.

How would I go about doing something like that?

here is my code in my move.java class if this helps: The method i'm working on is the Move (String str) method.

```
public class Move implements Comparable<Move>{
    static final int PASS_VALUE = 0; 
    int row, col; 
    boolean movement;
    int pass;
    int pos;
    Board board; 
    /**
     * 
     * Default constructor that initializes a pass move
     */
    Move(){
        row = PASS_VALUE; 
        col = PASS_VALUE;
    }//Move default contructor
   /**
    * 
    * @param rowValue
    * @param colValue 
    */
    Move(int rowValue, int colValue){
        row = rowValue; 
        col = colValue; 
    }//Move constructor

    /**
     * 
     * @param oldMove -- Move to be copied 
     */
    Move(Move oldMove){
        row = oldMove.row;
        col = oldMove.col; 

    }//Move clone constructor

    Move(String str) {
        //int i = Integer.parseInt( str );


    } //Move String constructor

    Move (int positions) {

    }//Move Positions constructor

    /**
     * 
     * @return string value of Move 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result ="";
        String headers = " abcdefgh";
        char colLetter = headers.charAt(col);
        result = colLetter + " " + row; 

        return result;
    }//toString
    /**
     * 
     * @param otherMove -- move to be compared 
     * @return 
     *      -1 if this move precedes otherMove
     *       0 if this move equals otherMove
     *       1 if this move succeeds otherMove
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Move otherMove){
        return 0;
    }//compareTo

   boolean isAMove() {
        return movement; 
    }
   boolean isAPass(){
       return row == PASS_VALUE;
   }
}//Move
```

***Keep in mind that the string variable (str) is being populated by this code:

```
Move getOpponentMove(BufferedReader keyboard) throws IOException {
        OthelloOut.printComment("Please enter your move");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String initializeStr = keyboard.readLine();
        Move opponentMove = new Move(initializeStr);

        return opponentMove;
    }
```

Comment: Integer.parseInt might be a place to start at..

Comment: `W c 3` ... `6 is the row` ?

Comment: do what? work on the game? parse user input? redraw the game board?

Comment: @Fareed Warrad; you might want to reword your title as you're doing a little more than converting a string to an integer

Comment: You can do a split with space as delimiter, have a string "abcdef...yz" and getter the index from it to get the number corresponding to your letter, and use parseInt to transform the string to the integer for the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is *strictly* of the form "a b" where a is in the range a a - z, and b is a number in the range 0 - 9 then do something like

```
/* s is your string */
int row = s.charAt(0) - 'a' + 1;
int col = s.charAt(2) - '0' + 1;
```

where I've exploited the ASCII character number values and the fact that 'a' is a byte data type.

Of course, in production, you ought to pre-validate `s` (check its length, whether or not the second character is a space etc. You could even use a regular expression check via Java's `String.matches` method). All you'd have to do is check if

```
s.matches("[a-z] [0-9]")
```

is true. My method is a throwback to the good old C days.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- split using space as delimiter
- indexOf(letter) in "abcdefg....xyz"
- Integer.parseInt(digit)

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the following order:

Assuming you have an input of the form:

```
String input = new String("W c 3");
```

1.Parse the input with split():

```
String color = input.split(" ")[0];
String column = input.split(" ")[1];
```

2.For the int variable, call the method parseInt()

```
int row = Integer.parseInt(input.split(" ")[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (comments explain it):

```
// create an array of the alphabet from a - z
public String[] alpha = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}; //...etc.

// here is your value
String input = "e 5";

// split it at the space
String[] split = input.split(" ");

// find it in the array and add 1 to get your row (because arrays start at 0)
int row = Arrays.asList(alpha).indexOf(split[0]) + 1;

// get the column as well
int column = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
```

Comment: notwithstanding the fact that the *shall we call it the augmented ellipsis operator `....`* is syntatically invalid.

Comment: @Bathsheba was assuming in this context it would be understood as "etc' or something equivalent to a range. My apologies and edit of my answer.